# How to go count all of the atoms in a list (or a list of nested lists) when you use recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I am creating a recursive function that counts the number of atoms inside a list. It should be able to count the atoms of lists that are nested. 
For example: (a (b c) e d) or (a (b c (g e)) e d), it should count b and c separately or b, c, e, and d separately and not as a whole.

This is the function that I have created:

```lisp
(defun  count-atoms (mylist)
    (cond
    ((null mylist) 0)
    ((listp (car mylist)) (count-atoms (car mylist)))
    ((atom (car mylist)) (+ 1 (count-atoms (rest mylist))))
    )
)
```

The output I get is 3 but it should be 5 (based from (a (b c) e d)). I am guessing that the function stops the moment it reaches c. How do i make the function not stop at c and make it go back to the outermost list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way we can reason about the problem -

- If the input is `null`, return zero

  > ```
  > '( )
  >   ^
  >   | 0 atoms
  > ```
- (inductive) Otherwise the input has *at least one* element. If `car` is a list, call `count-elements` on `car` *and* `cdr`. Add the two results together and return.

  > ```
  > '( a         b c d ... )
  >    ^         ^
  >    |         | count atoms in cdr <-
  >    |                                \
  >    | count atoms in sublist   <------\_ add together
  > ```
- (inductive) Otherwise the input has at least one element that is *not* a list. Call `count-elements` on `cdr`. Add one to the result and return.

  > ```
  > '( a         b c d ... )
  >    ^         ^
  >    |         | count atoms in cdr <-
  >    |                                \
  >    | one atom      <-----------------\_ add together
  > ```

Do you see where your program differs?

Comment: My program does not add the rest of the list if car is a list?

Comment: Bingo! You got it :)

Comment: My god HAHA! Thank you very much! I fixed it! :D

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you are ignoring the tail in the second clause.

```lisp
(defun count-atoms (tree)
  "Count atoms in all leaves of the tree, ignoring terminating NIL."
  (if tree
      (+ (if (atom (car tree))
             1
             (count-atoms (car tree)))
         (count-atoms (cdr tree)))
      0))
```

now

```lisp
(count-atoms '(a (b c) e d))
==> 5
(count-atoms '(a (b c (g e)) e d))
==> 7
(count-atoms '(a (b c (g e)) nil e d))
==> 8
```